# upgrade from Ubuntu 8.04 LTS with an old computer

Tags: upgrade

I have an old Dell Latitude D610, 500MB RAM, and a 11 GB partition available for Linux (a 30 GB partition is full with data, and on a 15 GB partition I still have Windows). I have it still running on 8.04 LTS. As this is no longer supported I would like to update it. Upgrading to 10.04 LTS failes as it askes me for 5 GB of free disk space which I don't have. What options do I have with my computer and how should I proceed?

Comment: Your PC is definitely to slow for Ubuntu Unity use Xubuntu or Lubuntu.

Comment: @Xubu-Tur From the requirements Xubuntu seems to be just as recommended and if I understand right, maybe a bit more straight forward to use. You would recommend both or might Xubuntu be already at the limit? I guess programms I can install all with both versions as also with Ubuntu?

Comment: With 512MB you are at the minimum from Xubuntu requirements it should be run but how smooth i cant't say it. Just try it you can switch to Lubuntu later if you want, its possible without reinstall (http://www.howtogeek.com/107368/how-to-install-the-lightweight-lxde-desktop-on-ubuntu/).

Answer (score 0):

Free some data using a "Disk Analyzer Tool".

The best option to do is to:

1. Backup everything you want to save to Google Drive
2. Download the new Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (You could get back the Gnome Desktop Back if you want http://goo.gl/OR2Oyz)
3. Create a bootable in a flash drive with ubuntu http://goo.gl/9727vE
4. Then try reinstalling it

Comment: Will this delete personal settings and data? I have as good as no personal data on the "linux-drive". Are 11GB (total space, now free are 2GB) be sufficient?

Comment: That's why you should save you data in http://drive.google.com (15 GB free), it will delete all you data otherwise.